# Move one reord to top

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have the below table (marked yellow). I am in a situation to generate the output (marked green) like this.

[image]

Conditions to use in the query:

1. When `cal_wk` is 1 then `target_hrs` value should take from `cal_wk` 2
2. When `target_hrs` is empty then `target_hrs` should be maximum of the result

I am trying the case statement like

```
select 
    r.hour_val,
    case 
       when us.calwk = 1 
          then 2 
          else us.calwk 
    end as cal_wk,
    hrswk as target_hrs, u.uid 
from 
    table1 us
inner join 
    users u on u.username = us.username 
inner join 
    table2 r on u.uid = r.uid 
where 
    us.yr = 2016 
    and u.uid = 2643 
    and r.cur_month = 7 
    and r.week_val = us.calwk 
order by 
    us.calwk
```

This is just changing `cal_wk` value not `target_hrs`.

Could any one write a query to generate the `expected_target_hrs`?

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select
Case when calwk = 1 then wk2_max
     When calwk = 0 then max
     Else target_hrs end as expected_target_hours
From [table name]
Inner join
  (Select max(case when calwk = 2 then target_hrs else 0 end) as wk2_max,
  Max(target_hrs) as max
  From [table name])
On 1 = 1
```

Following your update to the question, you will need to replace [table name] with that join.

Comment: I see the question has been adjusted slightly and reposted, and then an answer accepted elsewhere.